# run python cells in vscode

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I would like to run python cells with vscode.

For example:

```
#%%
import numpy as np
import os
from PIL import Image
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_curve

from tqdm import tqdm

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('seaborn')
```

I put `#%%` before the codes. However, when I click "run cell", there is no result come out, but just one error: **({"message": "'_xsrf' argument missing from POST", "reason": null})**

[image]

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: have you completed the prereqs? https://donjayamanne.github.io/pythonVSCodeDocs/docs/jupyter_prerequisites/

Comment: After I restart mscode, it works....

Answer (score 1):

I met exactly the same error.

It's fixed after the extension "VS Code Jupyter Notebook Previewer" is installed and reloaded.

Answer (score 0):

In the new version of VSCode the jupyter is integrated.